# Freeform plugin: Email Notification Templates Directory Path: Not set correctly

Tags: freeform

Freeform plugin:
I keep seeing this " Email Notification Templates Directory Path: Not set correctly " in my diagnostics section and can't access my templates. I have a folder in the root of my files named freeform_emails. Please help me figure out what is wrong with my path.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `freeform_emails` folder is at the same "level" as `config`, `storage` etc?

It should be moved to inside your main `templates` folder.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this before and just tried it again but still receive the same messaging and can't access my email templates.